# How can I print a new array element every day?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops

I'm trying to pick a new element of my array every day starting at midnight, and then once all elements have been used, jump back to the start of the array. What would be the best way to do so? Here's what I have so far.

```
import UIKit

var wordsArray = [String] ()

wordsArray = ["Hallo","Apfel","Geburtstag","Pherd","Angst"]

let date = NSDate ()
let calendar:NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.day = 1

while wordsArray (0..<2) {
  gregorian.date(byAdding: NSCalendar.Unit.day, value: $0, to: now, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))
}
```

Comment: Is your problem how to "jump back to the start to the array" or how to display something every midnight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to use a certain array element every day, and these elements should be chosen cyclically.
So the main problem is how to do something every day at midnight.
This can be achieved using a `Timer`:

```
// First determine coming midnight
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let nextDay = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())
let comingMidnight = calendar.startOfDay(for: nextDay!)

// Then start a time coming midnight, and repeat it every day
// Please note that 24 * 60 * 60 is not completely correct considering daylight saving times
// Sometimes days have 23 hours and sometimes 25 hours!
_ = Timer.init(fireAt: comingMidnight, interval: 24 * 60 * 60, target: self, selector: Selector(("timerFired")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

// And this is the timer callback:
func timerFired(timer: Timer) {
    // Here you can select the next element in your array, any do what is required
    // For selecting the elements cyclically, see the other answers!
}
```

This code has not been tested, but it should give you an idea how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap around the array use the modulo operator, it devides `index / number of items in the array` and returns the remainder of the division – in this case always `0...4`

```
let wordsArray = ["Hallo","Apfel","Geburtstag","Pferd","Angst"]

for i in 0..<10 {
   print(wordsArray[i % wordsArray.count])
}
```

Create an index variable in your code

```
var index = 0
```

and increment it this way

```
index = (index + 1) % wordsArray.count
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way I could think of.

```
    var wordsArray = [String] ()
    wordsArray = ["Hallo","Apfel","Geburtstag","Pherd","Angst"]
    let secondsInDay = (60 * 60 * 24)
    let dayNumber = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 / Double(secondsInDay))
    let selectedNumber = dayNumber % wordsArray.count
    let chosenWord = wordsArray[selectedNumber]
    print(chosenWord)
```

EDIT: another method hopefully satisfying a complaint

```
    var wordsArray = [String] ()
    wordsArray = ["Hallo","Apfel","Geburtstag","Pherd","Angst"]

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let date = Date()
    let yearNumber = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
    let monthNumber = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    let dayNumber = calendar.component(.day, from: date)

    let daysInYear = Double(yearNumber) * 12.0 * 365.25
    let daysInMonth = Double(monthNumber) * 30.42
    let totalNumber = daysInYear + daysInMonth + Double(dayNumber)

    let selectedNumber = Int(totalNumber) % wordsArray.count
    let chosenWord = wordsArray[selectedNumber]

    print(chosenWord)
```

Comment: **Don't** use `60 * 60 * 24` as the duration of a day, that need not be correct. In regions with daylight saving time, a day can have 23, 24, or 25 hours. Always use the appropriate calendar methods.

Comment: But it all averages the same.... This would technically work with making small adjustments...

Comment: @MartinR I added another method using the calendar components, but it still uses averages. The whole point of designing it this way is to ensure that no matter how many days that the App keeps running it is always the next line in the array on the following day. If you throw it together where is only considers which day of the month or year, it resets the loop at the beginning of the corresponding month/year.